# Sum of 2 positive irrational numbers is irrational?

Tags: proof-explanation, radicals, irrational-numbers

So, I know how the sum of 2 irractional numbers as a whole can be rational. For example, an irrational number $a$ and it's negative counterpart $-a$ have a sum of zero and so the sum is rational. But what if both of the terms had to be positive? Is there a way to make it rational?

My own sort of answer:
I think that you can split a number into something like $\sqrt{2}$ and $2 - \sqrt{2}$ and those 2 would sum up to a rational number $2$. Would that be an acceptable answer though, and if so how would we prove that the difference of a rational number and an irrational number is irrational?

Comment: $(2+\sqrt{2})+(2-\sqrt{2})=4$. Both summands are positive.

Comment: Your answer works fine, assuming you know that $2-\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.   Your second question needs to precede this.  Try a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Suppose we had $a-b=c$ with $a$ and $c$ rational and $b$ irrational. What could you say about $a-c$?

Comment: But from this, is there a method to prove that a rational number $\pm$ an irrational number is indeed irrational without use of a calculator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be two rational numbers and let $i$ be an irrational number. If possible, let
$$r_1-i=r_2$$
This implies
$$r_1-r_2=i$$
But, we know the difference of two rationals must be a rational number. This gives us a contradiction.